# php overlapping Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to find all the results for Regex statement Which works to find the word to search for and ten words before and after.

My problem is not Regex statement but overlapping in statements.

*I searched a lot but could not find a solution ,please help me*

```
        /**
 * @param $q
 * @param $files
 * @return string
 */
public function search($q, $files)
{
    $regexp = '/(?:\w+\W+){0,10}\b' . $q . '\b(?:\W+\w+){0,10}/';
    $files = explode(",", $files);
    try{
    $files = File::find($files);
    $data = array();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $url = $file->file_path;
        preg_match_all($regexp, file_get_contents($url), $data[], PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    }

    $result = array();
    array_walk_recursive($data, function ($v, $k) use (&$result) {
        $result[] = $v;
    });
    return response()->json($result,200);
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return response()->json("error", 500);
    }
}
```

---

**input :**

Wikipedia is a free online encyclopedia, created and edited by volunteers around the world and hosted by the Wikimedia Foundation

word for search : and

**output i want:**

1. Wikipedia is a free online encyclopedia, created and edited by volunteers around the world and hosted by the
   o
2. online encyclopedia, created and edited by volunteers around the world and hosted by the Wikimedia Foundation

---

Comment: Please add input string to your question.

Comment: and desired output as we are at it

Comment: Have you tried to make quantifiers ungreedy ? Like that `{0,10}?` or using `U` flag ?

Comment: Does anybody also get brain-stuck because `$data[]` in `preg_match_all()` works? But if you do your own function you can not do stuff like this??? `function foo(&$r){var_dump($r);} $data=array(); foo($data[]);print_r($data);`

Comment: Do you need two outputs?!

Comment: is not my  complate code

Comment: Elaborate please. @JustOnUnderMillions

Comment: please see this 
https://regex101.com/r/TvxgMT/2
i want get every word

Comment: @revo I have never seen an passed argument like `$data[]` at any place and after some checks i have noted that this only work for internal php functions. See my update in the last comment. This is so un-straight within php. Basicly `preg_match_all` the `$matches` parameter is taken as reference. UPDATE: It works also on self-made functions, but why?

Comment: @revo i want two match in this example

Comment: There's no `and` in the final words and you already passed 10. Make the ending unlimited or expand to 12. https://regex101.com/r/TvxgMT/3

Comment: @Dan Miller yes but not resolve the problem

Comment: @chris85 no, i want get every word (and) and 10 word before and after it

Comment: `edited by volunteers around the world and hosted by the` are 10 words after `and`. Then `Wikipedia is a free online encyclopedia, created` is 0 - 10 words before `and`, which is what your regex says.

Comment: @chris85 i have two and in my example ,the problem is :second 'and' will be overlapped by first 'and' regex statement

Comment: I don't know what you want. Maybe this will give you a starting point. https://eval.in/783952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

*Because requirements weren't clear enough I had to change whole solution.*

PHP code:

```
$str = 'Wikipedia is a free online encyclopedia, created and edited by volunteers around the world and hosted by the Wikimedia Foundation';
// Split into words
$words = preg_split('~ +~', $str);
// Find all indexes of our keyword `and`
$indexes = array_keys($words, 'and');
// Number of preceding or following words
$numberOfWords = 10;
// Iterate over them
foreach ($indexes as $i) {
    // Use `array_slice()` to extract words before and after our keyword and join them together using `implode()`
    $sentences[] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, ($i - $numberOfWords > 0) ? $i - 10 : 0, $i + $numberOfWords));
}
print_r($sentences);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Wikipedia is a free online encyclopedia, created and edited by volunteers around the world and hosted by
    [1] => online encyclopedia, created and edited by volunteers around the world and hosted by the Wikimedia Foundation
)
```

Comment: thanks very much ,Can I match the longest sentence for each word, I do not want every result?

Comment: *The longest* means one sentence only. Do you only need the longest one sentence?

Comment: no, i want   longest  for every word i'm searching for,in your result i want  0 and 4

Comment: i want the best match for the word and ten before and after that

Comment: 0 and 4 are two matches for first `and` not the second.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Do you need matches for second `and` eventually or just first two long match of first `and`?

Comment: sorry for my english ,i want get this two result with each other
this for first 'and' https://regex101.com/r/PLNPyF/1 and this for second 'and' https://regex101.com/r/9JZNcG/1 ,With a presence the first 'and' in second example